# Proper use of jQuery `stop`

Tags: jquery, mouseover, fade

I understand that the `stop()` method in jQuery is used to `Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements` (according to jQuery.com). I have an image gallery on my site where images are loaded when a user hovers his mouse over the image's thumbnail. This worked very well when I used `.click()` instead of `.mouseover()`; however, when I changed to `mouseover` the loading of the images was slightly laggy and far too slow for a fluid mouseover effect. I want to try to use .stop() so that there is no lag when a user aggressively moves his mouse from image to image but the code I'm using does not seem to have much of an effect at all.

The site can be viewed by [Clicking Here](http://blacktiephotographers.com/weddings/)

```
function showCurrent(img){
            inAnimation=true;
            img.toggleClass('current').stop().fadeIn(100,function(){
                var title=img.attr('title');
                inAnimation=false;
            });

            current.fadeOut(function(){
                current.removeClass('current'); 
            });
            current=img;
        }
```

What's happening:

The `showCurrent()` function is called when the thumbnail is moved over by the mouse. The current image is given the appropriate class, and then fades in (very quickly as you can see, I set it to 100 ms). So, I figured this should be very fluid and quick but it's not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try change "stop()" to "stop(true, true)"

Comment: I changed as you suggested. Something still seems, well, "off" - what do you think? Is this behaving properly?